# Unable to tag issue using release plugin

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm working on a maven modular project and now I'm trying to release it. I have successfully executed half on release:prepare, but when the plugin in tries to tag the progect i get unable to tag error.

Now I try to explain you the trouble. My modular project is composed from a few modules (model,services,rest,web-app, etc),

```
  |-- parent
     |-- model
         pom.xml
     |-- services
         pom.xml
     |-- rest
         pom.xml
     |-- web-app
         pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

I decided to use the same version for all modules then I run the following command:

> mvn release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true

During the process the version number of all my Poms is updated in a correct way and maven successfully commit them in my scm repository. I configured maven:release plugin in this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <providerImplementations>
                <svn>javasvn</svn>
            </providerImplementations>
            <checkModificationExcludes>
                <checkModificationExclude>.project</checkModificationExclude>
                <checkModificationExclude>.settings</checkModificationExclude>
                <checkModificationExclude>.classpath</checkModificationExclude>
            </checkModificationExcludes>
            <arguments>-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true</arguments>    
        </configuration>
<plugin>
```

I had to add the arguments tag because I use artifactory like repository manager over https. The  release:prepare is failing with this error when it attempts to create the tag for the release and throws this error:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to tag SCM

Provider message:
SVN tag failed.
Command output:
svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/home/svn/myCompany/test/trunk/parent'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmTagPhase.execute(ScmTagPhase.java:136)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:206)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:104)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:302)
        ... 22 more
```

The updated parent's pom from where I run the release:prepare command is configured in this way:

```
 <scm>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://192.168.0.10/home/svn/myCompany/test/tags/parent-2.1.0</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

On eclipse I shared the parent project a this address and I'm able to reach it correctly

```
svn://192.168.0.10/home/svn/aiem/test/trunk/parent
```

Where am I doing wrong?
How can I fix it?

Comment: can you check your server's error.log  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved changing the following things (pre release):

```
<scm>
   <connection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.0.10/home/svn/myCompany/test/tags/parent</connection>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.0.10/home/svn/myCompany/test/tags/parent</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

and I runned the command adding username and password

> mvn release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -Dusername=myUser -Dpassword=myPass